# Redis path structure issue with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I Have a simple Spring Boot application with Redis and H2.

**Follow the dependencies below:**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Follow the Redis configuration class:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair;
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Value("${redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;
    @Value("${redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfig = myDefaultCacheConfig(Duration.ofMinutes(10)).disableCachingNullValues();
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory()).cacheDefaults(cacheConfig)
                .withCacheConfiguration("tutorials", myDefaultCacheConfig(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))
                .withCacheConfiguration("tutorial", myDefaultCacheConfig(Duration.ofMinutes(1))).build();
    }
    private RedisCacheConfiguration myDefaultCacheConfig(Duration duration) {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(duration)
                .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }
}
```

**Application properties:**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# default path: h2-console
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-ui
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
redis.host=localhost
redis.port=6379
```

**Service class with the cacheable methods are:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.bezkoder.spring.redis.model.Tutorial;
import com.bezkoder.spring.redis.repository.TutorialRepository;

@Service
@EnableCaching
public class TutorialService {
  @Autowired
  TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;
  @Cacheable("tutorials")
  public List<Tutorial> findAll() {
    doLongRunningTask();
    return tutorialRepository.findAll();
  }
  @Cacheable("tutorials")
  public List<Tutorial> findByTitleContaining(String title) {
    doLongRunningTask();
    return tutorialRepository.findByTitleContaining(title);
  }
  @Cacheable(value = "tutorial", key = "#id" )
  public Optional<Tutorial> findById(long id) {
    doLongRunningTask();
    return tutorialRepository.findById(id);
  }
  public Tutorial save(Tutorial tutorial) {
    return tutorialRepository.save(tutorial);
  }
  @CacheEvict(value = "tutorial", key = "#tutorial.id")
  public Tutorial update(Tutorial tutorial) {
    return tutorialRepository.save(tutorial);
  }
  @CacheEvict(value = "tutorial", key = "#id")
  public void deleteById(long id) {
    tutorialRepository.deleteById(id);
  }
  @CacheEvict(value = { "tutorial", "tutorials", "published_tutorials" }, allEntries = true)
  public void deleteAll() {
    tutorialRepository.deleteAll();
  }
  @Cacheable("published_tutorials")
  public List<Tutorial> findByPublished(boolean isPublished) {
    doLongRunningTask();
    return tutorialRepository.findByPublished(isPublished);
  }
  private void doLongRunningTask() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**redis is saving the cache in the following structure
-> CacheName -> [Empty] -> cacheName::Id like the photo below**

[Image from Redis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsZ6c.png)

**How may I save redis cache without this path [Empty]?**